# Can't call com.android.settings.ChooseLockPassword activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call `ChooseLockPassword`activity from my own application, but an exception occurs.

***Java Code:***

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_RUN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.ChooseLockPassword"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<!-- Lock Screen. -->
<activity android:name="ChooseLockPassword"
          android:exported="true">

<action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />

</activity>
```

***Exception***

```
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.SystemPIN/com.test.SystemPIN.SystemPINTestActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN cmp=com.android.settings/.ChooseLockPassword } from ProcessRecord{40652e98 6739:com.test.SystemPIN/10033} (pid=6739, uid=10033) requires null
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

<snip>

04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN cmp=com.android.settings/.ChooseLockPassword } from ProcessRecord{40652e98 6739:com.test.SystemPIN/10033} (pid=6739, uid=10033) requires null
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
04-25 17:54:48.599: E/AndroidRuntime(6739):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1351)

<snip>
```

Comment: Your log formatting was really off.  I've reformatted some of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution and want to share it with you.

If you have android sources as me you can just made some modifications in Settings manifest file which located at ***packages\apps\settings\scr\com\android\settings\AndroidManifest.xml*** just modify

```
<activity android:name="ChooseLockPassword" android:exported="false"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>
```

line and set android:exported="true" instead of "false" after you can recompile sources and call that dialog with following lines

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_RUN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.ChooseLockPassword"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a permission denied exception, which means you need more permissions.  That the permission listed as required is `null`, suggests that you might not be allowed to call that activity at all.

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan: That specific flavor of security error means that the activity is not exported, and so it cannot be used except by its own application.

Comment: @CommonsWare And how I can export that activity ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I just want to call Screen Lock dialog, do you know how I can do that ? Thanks !

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan: You gather a gang, outfit them with high-powered weaponry, invade the Googleplex, take hostages, and force the core Android team to export that activity (note: this is illegal in the US). Then, you wait ~2 years until all older devices are replaced in the marketplace by devices that contain the modified firmware. In other words, *you* cannot export that activity -- the authors of that application can. If they wanted third parties to use that activity, not only would it be exported, but there would be documentation for how to use it, probably as part of the SDK.